# How to set up devise for 2 models using engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I'm having some troubles to set up Devise correctly with Engines.

In my **engine** I have:

`config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.router_name = :portal_core
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'PortalCore::User', module: :devise
```

`app/models/portal_core/user.rb`

```
module PortalCore
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :lockable
  end
end
```

All my tests pass here.
Then, in one of my **host** apps I have:

`config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :admin_users, class_name: 'AdminUser'
```

`app/models/admin_user.rb`

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  end
```

When I ran this test in the host app:

```
context "When not logged in" do
  it "redirect to new user session when try to access index" do
    process :index, method: :get, params:{}
    expect(response).to redirect_to(new_admin_user_session_path)
  end
end
```

I got this error: **NoMethodError:
       undefined method `portal_core' for # Devise::FailureApp:0x0000000008c9f1f0>**

If I mount the engine routes in the host app:

```
mount PortalCore::Engine => '/portal_core'
```

Then I got this error: **Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/admin_users/sign_in but was a redirect to http://test.host/.**

And if I try to start the server, it keeps redirecting with *401  Unauthorized*

Probably some configuration is missing, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if this is the solution or just a workaround.

In the host app devise initializer I set the router_name to nil:
`config.router_name = nil`
And it worked.

Any other solution is welcome!

Thanks!